# Cron is running in home directory instead of file directory

Tags: ruby, cron, rvm

I followed some other posts in stackoverflow and successfully setup cron with RVM using `rvm cron setup` and injected some ENV to the crontab file.

When I was troubleshooting why the `dotenv` gem is not working, I realised the following:

I placed my `test.rb` in file path `/home/myuser/ruby/test.rb` and had my `crontab` file as shown below:

```
* * * * * ruby /home/myuser/ruby/test.rb >> /home/myuser/ruby/output.log
```

and when I puts the output of the test.rb with `Dir.pwd`. The output states that the rb is run in the `/home/myuser/` directory instead of `/home/myuser/ruby` directory.

While I had a hotfix by manually changing the path. But I wonder why it is the case.

Comment: By default, if you don't change the directory you are currently in, the home of your user is "where you are in". What you would like to do is to "change" the directory, and then execute your script. Consider: `* * * * * cd /home/myuser/ruby/ && ruby ./test.rb >> /home/myuser/ruby/output.log`.

Comment: @PawełDawczak just tried. you are right! Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped! Just created proper answer! Good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, cron tasks of a user are executed from the user's home directory. In order to execute the script from proper directory, you have to "cd" to it.

Consider changing your crontab to:

```
* * * * * cd /home/myuser/ruby && ruby ./test.rb >> /home/myuser/ruby/output.log
```

Good luck!

Comment: Or just adapt the code to use absolute paths, like you already (needlessly) do with the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

According to @Pawel Dawczak who left the answer in the comment.

the solution is to rewrite the statement in crontab as

```
* * * * * cd /home/myuser/ruby && ruby test.rb >> /home/myuser/ruby/output.log
```

Thanks!